# How to find specific distance along routes using ArcGIS Pro?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, network-analyst, network-dataset

I have road layers (normal line ones as well as a network dataset) and a building point layer (consisting of one building).

I'd like to know where I end up if I travel a certain distance (say 1000 meters, for example) along the roads from the building?